# Evaluate $\sum _{k=1}^n (n-k) 2^k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

Using $$\sum_{k=0}^n2^k=2^{n+1}-1,$$
I would like to evaluate $$\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k)2^{k-1}.$$
This is A.1.4 From Aigner Course in Enumeration

Comment: Hello, what is meant with the "sum rule"? Can you not just give a proof by induction?

Comment: yes induction works to prove the first, but the key concept was so see that its a finite geometric sum. Then to differentiate it.

Comment: i got blocked after i have posted this. I dont know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with
$$(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+\ldots+x^2+x+1)=x^{n+1}-1$$
you get
$$x^n+x^{n-1}+\ldots+x^2+x+1=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$
Then plugging $x=2$ you have the answer
$$2^n+2^{n-1}+\ldots+2^2+2+1=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2-1}=2^{n+1}-1$$
Then you can write
$$\sum _{k=1}^n (n-k)2^{k-1} =\sum _{k=1}^n n\,2^{k-1} -\sum _{k=1}^n k 2^{k-1}=\ldots$$
and simplify extracting the parts that do not contain $k$
$$\ldots=n\sum _{k=1}^n 2^{k-1} -\sum _{k=1}^n k 2^{k-1}$$
The first sum is $n(2^n-1)$ because the index doesn't start from 0, that is
$$\sum _{k=1}^n 2^{k-1}=\sum _{k=0}^n 2^{k-1}-1=2^n-1$$

Now observe the following. Consider $1 + x + x^2+x^3+\ldots + x^4=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$

Differentiate wrt $x$ the left side. You get $1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3+\ldots+nx^{n-1}$

Differentiating the right side you get the formula
$$1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3+\ldots+nx^{n-1}=\frac{(n (x-1)-1) x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}$$
Plugging $x=2$ we have
$$1 + 2\times2 + 3\times 2^2 + 4\times2^3+\ldots+n2^{n-1}=\frac{(n (2-1)-1) 2^n+1}{(2-1)^2}$$
finally
$$\sum _{k=1}^n k 2^{k-1}=-1-2^n n+2^{n+1} n-2^n+1 =2^n n-2^n+1$$
The answer is then
$$\sum _{k=1}^n (n-k)2^{k-1} =n(2^n-1)-(2^n n-2^n+1)=2^n-n-1$$

Comment: Looks like a long answer because I explained all the passages

Comment: About half way ... $1 + x + x^2+x^3+\ldots + x^{\color{red}{n}}=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$ not 4 ?

Comment: this is the correct answer, cant vote

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k)2^{k-1}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n-k+1)2^{k}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n2^{k}-k2^{k}+2^{k})$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} n2^{k}- \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k2^{k}+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{k}$$
$$n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{k}- \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k2^{k}+ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{k}$$

$$ n\big[2^{n}-1\big] - \big[2^{n}(n-2) + 2\big] + \big[2^{n}-1\big]$$

> $$n(2^{n}-1)-2^{n}(n-2) + 2^n-3$$